# Android Studio cannot find JUnit package

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

I just can't seem to get a test file to find Junit4. I've been trying forever and I'm just frustrated.  It says it can't find symbol junit under org. Everything I've googled (for days), and even the android docs say this is how to do it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my test class

```
import org.junit.Test;
import android.app.Application;



public class ApplicationTest {
  //  @Test
    public ApplicationTest() {


    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
   //buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "stuff.morestuffs"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

heres my project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I'm using Android Studio 1.4

Comment: What directory are your test files in?  Assuming you are trying to set up testing for the JVM, with your gradle listed above, they should be in a subdirectory of `test` .  A common mistake is to have them in the `androidTest` subdirectory.

Comment: They are in the androidTest directory, they're currently located: `app\src\androidTest\java\stuff.morestuffs`. Let me try moving them

Comment: For unit testing on the JVM, move them to `app\src\test\java\stuff.morestuffs`.   The `testCompile` is for JVM dependencies.  `androidTestCompile` is for DVM (dalvik/on device) unit testing.

Comment: @iagreen I moved them to that directory, but android studio just won't recognize it as a class/code file, has a red (!) on the file, and none of the code completion/validation works..... any suggestions? I've been poking it for a bit now with no luck...Are tests that run on the JVM not supposed to be executed through AS?

Comment: You can run them from AS.  Check out this guide -- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: Under "Build Variants", I had "Android Instrument Tests" selected. When I changed this to "Unit Tests", android studio correctly recognized my file. All is good!  Thanks @iagreen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For unit tests (JVM tests) the root source directory should be `test`, not `androidTest` as for Android instrument tests.
2. Under "Build Variants", I had "Android Instrument Tests" selected. When I changed this to "Unit Tests", Android Studio correctly recognized my file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem when I added following dependency to `build.gradle`:

> androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

If you have to test more than some separate methods and you want to test your Activity or Fragments you have to add it.